# Using MySQLdb Python module with mysql_old_password

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I need to use Python to connect to a database that uses the mysql_old_password authentication plugin. I do not have db admin access so I cannot change this setting, so please do not suggest that.

I just installed the MySQLdb module, downloaded [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5). Other stackoverflow questions on this matter have led me to believe that it is possible to use the old authentication with this module, but when I set up my connection (db info removed for privacy reasons), I get the following error:

```
('Unexpected error:', <class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_db.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "convert_db.py", line 25, in main
    prod_con = MySQLdb.connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'mysql_old_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/mysql_old_password.so, 2): image not found")
```

This seems to indicate that I just need to download the plugin image from somewhere - is this possible? Or is there some field I can set using MySQLdb that will allow me to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_old_password` support was removed from the mysql client libraries in [5.7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html), so you're probably using a newer version of the client libraries then that.

You'll have to downgrade your client library version if you need to connect to a server using old password authentication.

You could also try [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) instead of MySQLdb, which should [still have](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/70f477726cc6fbb7d348616129a568057473faff/pymysql/connections.py#L1151) support for old password hashes.

Comment: Okay, I've downgraded to MySQL 5.6, but now when I try to connect I get the following: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2049, "Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)")`. This seems to indicate that MySQLdb simply cannot handle the old password hashes - am I correct?

Comment: In any case, pymysql does work for my purposes. Thanks so much!

Comment: To disable secure_auth in MySQLdb you'd probably need to create a [MySQL config file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) with `secure_auth=off` in the `[client]` section and then pass its path as the `read_default_file` argument to [`connect()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes). But using pymysql instead is probably the more portable solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database server which still uses old_password, I used pymysql. 
All other modules were giving error 'Malformed Packet'